# Модель машинного обучения на временных рядях для оценки качества связи

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, временные-ряды

Необходимо сделать модель машинного обучения на временных рядях для оценки качества связи.

Датасет собирался на протяжении 14 дней (15.01.2016-28.01.2016) и содержит в себе 7026706 строк и 6 колонок: Dest. IP, Last hop IP, LQ, NLQ, Cost.
В данный датасет я добавил колонку с датой для всех строк и убрал столбцы Dest. IP, Last hop IP, NLQ, Cost. В итоге у меня получился след. датасет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я построил график зависимости значения LQ от даты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сделал прогноз по последнему наблюдению (24 часа): 0.9105833333333333

Код на данный момент:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime, time
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

#Формирование датасета
files = glob("/content/newDataset/*.tsv")
dataset = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", skiprows=1) for f in files], 
           ignore_index=True)

n_samples = 7026706 
dt_from = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-15 00:00:00.000000")
dt_to = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-28 23:59:59.999999")
dataset["DateTime"] = pd.date_range(dt_from, dt_to, periods=n_samples)
dataset['LQ'] = dataset.LQ.astype('float64')
#df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
del dataset['Dest. IP']
del dataset['Last hop IP']
del dataset['NLQ']
del dataset['Cost']
#dataset.drop(['Dest. IP', 'Last hop IP', 'NLQ', 'Cost'], axis=1)
print(dataset)

#График
def plot_series(time, series, format="-", start=0, end=None, label=None):
    plt.plot(time[start:end], series[start:end], format, label=label)
    plt.xlabel("DateTime")
    plt.ylabel("LQ")
    if label:
        plt.legend(fontsize=14)
    plt.grid(True)

def trend(time, slope=0):
    return slope * time

time = dataset['DateTime']
series = dataset['LQ']
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 6))
#plot_series(time, series)
#plt.show()
dataset.set_index("DateTime")["LQ"].rolling(window=600000).mean().plot()

#прогноз по последнему наблюдению
def moving_average(series, n):
    return np.average(series[-n:])

moving_average(dataset.LQ, 24)
```

Поскольку не силён в машинном обучении, то:

1. Надо ли мне делать сглаживание временного ряда?
2. Какую модель можно использовать для данной задачи?
3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что выбросов выбросов нет и ряд является стационарным?

Файлы [проекта](https://mega.nz/file/7cgzQKIa#QP_dMCpPYMs2m3KGKS2gqcZieAGj8cmvQSC7cVvi3N0).

График зависимости LQ от даты/времени и графики корреляции
[image]
[image: FBProphet]

Comment: Можете запаковать и выложить ваш файл на кокой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: 14 дней - может оказаться слишком мало. Часто в таких временных рядах присутствует компонент сезонности, например выходные и праздничные дни. Сезонность может сильно влиять на поведение ряда. Для того, чтобы аккуратно вычленить сезонность обычно берут данные за один год

Comment: @maxU https://mega.nz/file/7cgzQKIa#QP_dMCpPYMs2m3KGKS2gqcZieAGj8cmvQSC7cVvi3N0

Comment: @MaxU Имеет смысл брать SARIMA модель?

Comment: имеет смысл разложить на компоненты и проверить присутствует ли сезонность. Как я уже писал выше сезонность может зависеть от поры года и др. и для этого обычно нужна выборка за 1+ лет...

Comment: @MaxU вы имеете ввиду строить график как на скиншоте в посте по каждому дню и искать закономерность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказали в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1121378/217579) - вместо применения скользящего среднего можно сделать обычный `downsampling`, т.е. сгруппировать временной ряд, например, по N-минут и взять среднее для группы. Это значительно уменьшит вашу выборку и ускорит обучение модели.

Ваш ряд имеет явные признаки дневной сезонности - смотрите второй график. Чтобы говорить о других видах сезонности - нужно иметь данные за более длинный период времени. Для более менее толковых прогнозов нужно иметь данные хотя бы за один год.

Практический пример (используем [FBProphet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from fbprophet import Prophet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# %matplotlib

### читаем данные
data_dir = Path(r"D:\download\data")

df = (pd
      .concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", skiprows=1, usecols=["LQ"])
               for f in data_dir.glob("*.tsv")], 
              ignore_index=True)
      .rename(columns={"LQ": "y"}))
dt_from = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-15 00:00:00.000000")
dt_to = pd.to_datetime("2016-01-28 23:59:59.999999")
df.insert(0, "ds", pd.date_range(dt_from, dt_to, periods=len(df)))

### усредняем данные до минуты (resampling -> 1 min. frequency)
data = df.set_index("ds").resample("1T").mean().reset_index()

### разбиваем данные не обучающую и тестовые выборки
train_test_split = int(0.7 * len(data))
train, test = np.split(data, [train_test_split])


### строим модель
model = Prophet(daily_seasonality=True)
model.fit(train)

forecast = model.predict(test)

ax = data.set_index("ds")["y"].plot(figsize=(20, 8))
forecast.set_index("ds")["yhat"].plot(ax=ax)
ax.legend(["Ground truth", "Predicted"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
### разложение временного ряда на компоненты и визуализация
# c:\temp\forecast_comps.png
fig_comps = model.plot_components(forecast)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS если временной ряд будет содержать больше данных (например 1+ лет), то стоит добавить недельную и месячную сезонности и информацию о праздниках.

Comment: Попробовал ваш код (правда не в локальном окружении, а в colab.google.research). У меня получились абсолютно иные графики тренда и сезонности, а также график модели. Такое возможно?

Comment: @gangsta, вы запускали код один-в-один __ничего__ не меняя и получили совершенно другие результаты?

Comment: совершенно верно (за исключением чтения файлов из каталога ввиду запуска не на локальном хосте (под винду не совсем ясно как установить либу)). Скриншот приложил в конец поста.

Answer (score 4):

1. Ваш исходный ряд имеет весьма специфический вид -  фрагмент его на рисунке внизу. По нему качество связи можно оценивать по разным показателям. Один из них -  изменение среднего значения за период. (Например - за секунду, минуту, день) Непонятно зачем вы делали скользящее среднее, если для указанной операции вам надо было просто усреднять по периоду.
2. Полученный таким образом ряд необходимо проверить на стационарность например, по критерию Dickey-Fuller или KPSS. Оба есть в пакете statsmodels.  Скорее всего ваш ряд окажется нестационарным.
3. Наличие сезонности тоже определяется не на глаз, а -  например -  через анализ автокорреляций.
4. Далее надо анализировать ваш ряд и строить прогнозы. Я бы прошелся по классическому списку (с поправкой на результаты пунктов 2 и 3) - Локальная регрессия, Экспоненциальное среднее, Хольта, Хольта-Винтерса, ARMA, ARIMA, SARIMA.
5. После чего можно делать и анализ.

И последнее. Мое личное мнение - оценивать качество связи по единственному показателю -  не верный путь. Если это учебная задача - то сойдет. Если реальный мониторинг - надо выполнять совместный анализ множества параметров.  Более того, из вашего LQ можно извлечь не только среднее значение, но дополнительные параметры - распределение интервалов между падениями ниже 1, распределение длин единичных интервалов, распределение реальных значений на отрезке и тд. Все это влияет на качество связи, я уже не говорю про другие параметры, которые вы отбросили. 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такой вопрос. Я вместо скользящего среднего усреднил по периоду (1 минута). Затем построил график зависимости LQ от даты/времени. И построил график автокорреляции и частичную автокорреляцию (скриншот приложил в пост). Как и для чего интерпретируются данные графики корреляции? По ним можно строить SARIMA модель? Каким образом образом определяются параметры для неё?

Comment: Быстрое затухание значений АКФ – простой тест на стационарность. Поэтому есть большое подозрение, что ваш ряд нестационарен.  Соответственно, параметр d (интегрирование) придется подбирать, но точно не 0.  По ЧАКФ можно предположить сезонность  равную 5.  Про интерпретацию посмотрите вот тут, например: https://ru.coursera.org/lecture/data-analysis-applications/vybor-arima-i-proghnozirovaniie-1lolc   Кстати, а что это за показатель LQ у вас?

Comment: Link Quality - качество связи с соседним узлом. Кстати, а критерий Дики-Фуллера, равный 0.000000, разве не говорит о том, что отвергается гипотеза о нестационарности ряда?

Comment: Вообще-то говоря критические значения теста Dickey — Fuller отрицательные.  При этом если расчетное значение критерия больше критического, то ряд НЕ стационарен. Но нулевое его значение смущает само по себе. Вы p-value считали? И кстати, сразу не заметил, гипотезе этого теста -  о  оравенстве нулю коэффициента b уравнения авторегрессии.

Comment: значение p-value - ноль

Comment: Значит у вас ошибки в расчетах. Или использовании программ.

Comment: Да, я заметил это. Когда запускал код на локальном хосте, то значение Дики-Фуллера оказалось равным 0.003064, а после преобразования Бокса-Кокса 0.001130. Хотя параметр Бокса-Кокса оказался вообще отрицательным -0.750347